# Dumping erc20 token transactions via rpc?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, json-rpc, external-api

I'd like to do dump **all transactions** of an erc20-token via the json-rpc interface. I've got a full node running but I'm lost, since the ethereum blockchain is harder to navigate than bitcoin for some reason.
I've looked all over github for a simple dump but there seems to be none, only implementations of the json-rpc interface.
Etherscan lists them, but only the last 100.000 and not every single one of them.

Below I've got a screenshot of what I'd like to save to a database.
[image: ethereum link transactions]

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to iterate over all the blocks in the chain using the eth_getBlockByNumber method, extracting transaction data from them